# how to start an activity inside a custom alertdialog

Tags: android

Here I use this `Activatedialog` method in `onPostExecute` inside registration >activity , and need to start a `login` activity when the alert dialog dissmiss ..however I tried to do this, but I get error.

[image]

```
 public void Activatedialog(String jsonmsg, final String name)
{

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ct);

    alert.setTitle("Activate Account");
    alert.setMessage(jsonmsg);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 

    final EditText input = new EditText(ct);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    Log.d("MYLOG","before +ve button click");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            {
                      String code = input.getText().toString();

                      Log.d("MYLOG","before try");
                      try{
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u",name ));
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code",code ));
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(ACTIVATION_URL,"POST", params);

                            Log.d("MYLOG","after request for json");

                            stcode = json.getJSONObject("activate").getInt("statuscode");
                            stmsg = json.getJSONObject("activate").getString("statusmessage");

                            Log.d("MYLOG","after json parsing : json data is "+stmsg+"stcodeis "+stcode);

                            if(stcode == 1)
                            {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                Log.d("MYLOG"," in check json data is "+stmsg+" stcodeis "+stcode);

                                Intent i = new ("LOGIN");startActivity(i);![i get this error][1]

                                Toast.makeText(ct, " "+stmsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else if(stcode == 0)
                            {
                                Log.d("MYLOG"," in check json data is "+stmsg+" stcodeis "+stcode);
                                Toast.makeText(ct, " "+stmsg+" "+stcode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                      }
                      catch(JSONException e)
                      {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          Toast.makeText(ct, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
            }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
              {
                        // Canceled.
                        Toast.makeText(ct, "Your Account is not Activated.Login to Activate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
    });

    alert.show();

}

 }
```

Comment: post your correct code.

Comment: Intent i = new ("LOGIN");startActivity(i) are u using this line?

Comment: That's why u are getting error of null pointer exception.

Comment: then what should i do to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

To start an Activity, the intent must have following parameters. A context and target activity. Lets start activity "Login.java" .

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Do you have an activity like "Login"? Also makle sure to declare the activity in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager(StartActivity.this);
```

AlertDialogManager constructor:

```
public void AlertDialogManager(final Context context) {

    activity = (Activity) context;

}
```

and you can launch the activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity , Login.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created intent incorrectly.

1> add the relevant activity you want to open say `Login`by adding new activity to the project.

2>create the intent as below

`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);`

3>start activity using the intent created

`startActivity(i);`